# java 17 corretto: `--add-opens` doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, reflection, migration, java-17, corretto

I'm trying to migrate a Spring Boot, Kotlin project to java 17 from 8.
We are using a communication framework that I'm trying to keep as-is for now.
The library is using reflection to access URL.host and URL.authority
This breaks at runtime with `java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private java.lang.String java.net.URL.host accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @3857f613`

I tried adding `--add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED` to the java command line but the exception is still raised.

Is there another setting for corretto?

Thanks,
Amos

Comment: Make sure you've added the flag as a VM argument, not as a program argument. It should be passed before the main class, or before `-jar`.

Comment: This was indeed the issue, thanks @jorn-vernee

Answer (score 0):

try to use --add-opens java.base/java.net.URL=ALL-UNNAMED

for example it was my solution in similar case (for surefire plugin)

```
<argLine>
    --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED
</argLine>
```